# Detect if Shift is pressed

Tags: javascript

I have a situation on a phone field. On this field, the user can type the following phone numbers:

(00)9999 9999 
(00)99999 9999 (in São Paulo Brasil) 
and 
1234*12 (Nextel Numbers)

On the field phone I configure an onkeydown event that call this javascript function:

```
function validateKeyDownPhone(event) {

    var c = event.keyCode
        keychar=String.fromCharCode(c)
        valid = true

    /**
     * Excluding enter, backspace, etc. 
     */
    if (c > 46 ) {          
        if (keychar != null) {  
            var re = new RegExp("^[0-9\*#\(\) ]+$")
            matched = keychar.match(re)
            valid = matched != null && matched.length > 0
        }
    }
    event.returnValue = valid
}
```

It works fine, but when the I press SHIFT + 5 results in %, for example.

How can I identify if the shift key was pressed?

Answer (score 4):

The [`event.shiftKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/shiftKey) attribute should tell you that information.

Answer (score 1):

Listen to the `keypress` instead of `keydown` event.  Then you can reject based on the actual typed character, not the pressed key.  So you don't have to to make guesses about the user's keyboard layout.  For example, option+5 on a mac does NOT type 5, but you would miss that if you only watch the state of the shift key.